# how to get response body from cxf outInterceptor

Tags: java, cxf

I am writing some code to collect some controller's request param and response body.

Since the project framework is apache CXF, which version is `3.1.18`,

I write an interceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor to collect param in phase `Phase.RECEIVE`, which is working.

But when a write an outInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor to collect the response of the controller, I find there no way for me to do this, there just one method `handleMessage(Message message)` in the interceptor, I can not fetch anything I want from the message

Can anybody help me? I am new to CXF. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from the other blob

```
package XXX.web.webservice.interceptor;  

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;  
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream;  
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;  
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;  
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;  
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  

public class ArtifactOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{  
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ArtifactOutInterceptor.class);  

    public ArtifactOutInterceptor() {  
        //这儿使用pre_stream，意思为在流关闭之前  
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);  
    }  

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {  

        try {  

            OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);  

            CachedStream cs = new CachedStream();  

            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cs);  

            message.getInterceptorChain().doIntercept(message);  

            CachedOutputStream csnew = (CachedOutputStream) message.getContent(OutputStream.class);  
            InputStream in = csnew.getInputStream();  

            String xml = IOUtils.toString(in);  

            //这里对xml做处理，处理完后同理，写回流中  
            IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), os);  

            cs.close();  
            os.flush();  

            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, os);  


        } catch (Exception e) {  
            log.error("Error when split original inputStream. CausedBy : " + "\n" + e);  
        }  
    }  

    private class CachedStream extends CachedOutputStream {  

        public CachedStream() {  

            super();  

        }  

        protected void doFlush() throws IOException {  

            currentStream.flush();  

        }  

        protected void doClose() throws IOException {  

        }  

        protected void onWrite() throws IOException {  

        }  

    }  

}
```